# Firebird problem when filtering a query with BOOLEAN value(s)

Tags: ms-access, odbc, firebird

I use Firebird 3.0.4 as a backend to an Access database with an ODBC driver version 2.0.5, both on 64 bit Windows platform. When trying to execute a query containing boolean values in the WHERE clause,the resulting set is empty and I also receive a #-413 error from Access.

Changing the BOOLEAN into SMALLINT, and re-building the backend, the queries execute like a breeze.
What is this?

Comment: Please post a [mre] and the full error message

Comment: maybe ODBC does not know boolean new type in FB3? maybe try ibprovider.com - Microsoft used to say ODBC obsolete and OLE-DB the future...

Comment: "Microsoft used to say ODBC obsolete and OLE-DB the future..." - That was many years ago. Microsoft has long since reversed its position and ODBC is preferred (for now, anyway).

Comment: @GordThompson that is why i said "used to say". However it influenced expectations of both app developers and libs developers for long. Just look at https://firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/ - it seems rather obvious that there is no active development, with last release in mid 2017 and general rate one new sub-minor version per 1 to 3 years.

Comment: @Arioch - Good points.

Comment: @ddmmaaxx - When you open the linked table in Datasheet View what do the boolean values look like?

Comment: Meantime I "discovered" that the problem is with ODBC. I transformed the boolean fields in small integer ones with check on entered values and after that on all is OK.

Comment: i tried the proposed download  after reading here about it, it's a 32 bit program that can't "see" my 64 bit databases...

Answer (score 0):

At first check your query right on the Firebird.
Just grab one of the free "Studios" like "SQL Manager Lite for InterBase & Firebird" and actually check the query.
If it works as it should ...consider "casting" the Boolean value to their numeric form.